# Is there a way to get datastore derived from a .csv file as tall array instead of a tall table in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, performance, csv

I started to handle a huge amount of data (derived from multi-electrode arrays cultured with neurons) that are too big to fit in RAM. So I started to use tall tables, but the performance is very poor.

Currently my working procedure is to load the .csv file using `datastore`, then store that using `tall`.

Unfortunately, when I want to load specific data into RAM with `gather`, it is very slow; I guess it would take me a whole week to analyse one experiment.

```
% get the file as tall table:

ds = datastore(fullfile(filepath,filename));
data = tall(ds);

% here is the bottleneck:

temp = data((i-1)*interval+2:interval*i+1,el); % specify one data column
tempTab = gather(temp);
```

I read that performance of tables is poor compared to matrices in MATLAB, so I wonder if there is a possibility to get data from the datastore as a tall array instead of a tall table?

Comment: You can simply access your column by using the right column's name: `mycol = data.YourColumnName`. `mycol` will be a tall array.

Comment: Thank you! That was a good hint! The issue was that I want to apply a butterworth filter on my data. Here in each colum the voltage values of one electrode ist stored. Assigning by .varname is great, but it's hard to go through nearly 400 columns. But it leads me to a working solution (see in answers)

Answer (score 0):

Since I want to apply a butterworth filter on all rows), I need a solution to loop through the data.

The possibility to apply a function to tall arrays is great, so I can simply do something like this:

```
filteredData = table2array(filterElectrode(ta(:,i))
```